# How to Zoom In/Out Photo on double Tap in the iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uitouch, touchesbegan, wwdc

I am going through the Sample code of iPhone WWDC 2010 - 104 PhotoScroller App.
It's working great with my project related images (PDF Page Images)

but I am struggling detect touches in the PhotoScroller App. The Zooming using multiple touches is handled by the ScrollVoiew. Now I want to Zoom In/out the photo on double Tap. The Touchesbegan method is being called in TilingView Class. Then I used [super touchesbegan: withevent:] and now the touches are in the ImageScrollView Class.

How to get these touch events in PhotoViewController.
How to achieve the zoom in and zoom out on touch ?

Can anyone help in this Regard ?

Comment: shouldn't you accept an answer already?

Answer (score 71):

I researched several different web sites and I came up with the following...

Place this code into your viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear method:

```
//////////////////////////////
// Listen for Double Tap Zoom

UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[self.scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];

[doubleTap release];
```

Add this to your header file:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer;
```

Add this to your implementation:

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {  

    if(self.scrollView.zoomScale > self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale)
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale animated:YES]; 
    else 
        [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale animated:YES]; 

  }
```

Currently this does not center upon the area where the user double tapped.

Comment: this does not work for me (IOS noob). do i put this in my view file that controls the xib actions or do I need to create a custom scoll view class?

Answer (score 65):

My code, based upon some of the code at link "[UIImageView does not zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10685932/uiimageview-does-not-zoom)"
This code handles toggling between zoomed in and zoomed out and will allow detection of a single tap along with a double tap. It also properly centers the zoom on the embedded image by applying the view transform on it. This code would go in the ImageScrollView class from the sample code.

```
- (void)setupGestureRecognisers:(UIView *)viewToAttach {

    UITapGestureRecognizer *dblRecognizer;
    dblRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                        action:@selector(handleDoubleTapFrom:)];
    [dblRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

    [viewToAttach addGestureRecognizer:dblRecognizer];
    self.doubleTapRecognizer = dblRecognizer;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer;
    recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                     action:@selector(handleTapFrom:)];
    [recognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:dblRecognizer];

    [viewToAttach addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
    self.tapRecognizer = recognizer;
}

- (void)handleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

   // do your single tap
}


- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {

    CGRect zoomRect;

    zoomRect.size.height = [_imageView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [_imageView frame].size.width  / scale;

    center = [_imageView convertPoint:center fromView:self];

    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - ((zoomRect.size.width / 2.0));
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - ((zoomRect.size.height / 2.0));

    return zoomRect;
}

- (void)handleDoubleTapFrom:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    float newScale = [self zoomScale] * 4.0;

    if (self.zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale)
    {
        [self setZoomScale:self.minimumZoomScale animated:YES]; 
    }
    else 
    {
        CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale 
                                   withCenter:[recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view]];
        [self zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the best solution since it actually zooms to the tap location.  I included a Swift version below based on this.

Comment: Thanks for the swift version!

Answer (score 40):

Here is a **Swift** solution based on [@possen's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/770313/possen) great answer.
- Put this in your view controller that contains the scrollview and is the scrollview delegate.
- This solution is great since it actually zooms to the tap location:

```
@IBAction func handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
        scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
    } else {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }
}

func zoomRectForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
    var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
    zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height / scale
    zoomRect.size.width  = imageView.frame.size.width  / scale
    let newCenter = scrollView.convert(center, from: imageView)
    zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
    zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
    return zoomRect
}
```

Comment: Are you sure? I have this code in my app [hashpic](https://appsto.re/us/4Zkg-.i) on the App Store. It might need to be updated for Swift 3 though.

Comment: As is, this doesn't work. The convert(_:from:) call should be changed to convert(_:to:) or scrollView and imageView on that line should be swapped. Per the docs, "The rectangle should be in the coordinate space of the view returned by viewForZooming(in:)" which in this case is the imageView. It was correct before Pavel Vavilov's edit. I've submitted an edit that corrects this.

Comment: Totally agree with @Shadowfacts - the convert(:from:) call must be changed to convert(:to:) and this would work correctly.

Answer (score 21):

**Swift 3**

Normally image zoom functionality is required with both double tap and pinch gesture, so I am providing complete solution to achieve the same. Double tap zoom is inspired by above answers and pinch zoom was taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014241/uiimageview-pinch-zoom-swift).

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    var imageView: UIImageView!
    var scrollImg: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let vWidth = self.view.frame.width
        let vHeight = self.view.frame.height

        scrollImg = UIScrollView()
        scrollImg.delegate = self
        scrollImg.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vWidth, height: vHeight)
        scrollImg.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 90, green: 90, blue: 90, alpha: 0.90)
        scrollImg.alwaysBounceVertical = false
        scrollImg.alwaysBounceHorizontal = false
        scrollImg.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        scrollImg.flashScrollIndicators()

        scrollImg.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollImg.maximumZoomScale = 10.0

        let doubleTapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer:)))
        doubleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
        scrollImg.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGest)

        self.view.addSubview(scrollImg)

        imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: vWidth, height: vHeight))
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "cat")
        imageView!.layer.cornerRadius = 11.0
        imageView!.clipsToBounds = false
        scrollImg.addSubview(imageView!)
    }

    func handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if scrollImg.zoomScale == 1 {
            scrollImg.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollImg.maximumZoomScale, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollImg.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func zoomRectForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height / scale
        zoomRect.size.width  = imageView.frame.size.width  / scale
        let newCenter = imageView.convert(center, from: scrollImg)
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
        return zoomRect
    }

    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return self.imageView
    }

}
```

Answer (score 16):

I combined the answers from @jayesh kavathiya and @possen into a single implementation which works pretty well, as long as you've set appropriate values for `self.minimumZoomScale` and `self.maximumZoomScale`.

```
- (void)doubleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer*)recognizer
{
    if (self.zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale)
    {
        [self setZoomScale:self.minimumZoomScale animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        CGPoint touch = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

        CGSize scrollViewSize = self.bounds.size;

        CGFloat w = scrollViewSize.width / self.maximumZoomScale;
        CGFloat h = scrollViewSize.height / self.maximumZoomScale;
        CGFloat x = touch.x-(w/2.0);
        CGFloat y = touch.y-(h/2.0);

        CGRect rectTozoom=CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
        [self zoomToRect:rectTozoom animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

use this code so it will zoom where you click.......

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {  
        if(zoomCheck){
            CGPoint Pointview=[recognizer locationInView:self];
            CGFloat newZoomscal=3.0;

            newZoomscal=MIN(newZoomscal, self.maximumZoomScale);

            CGSize scrollViewSize=self.bounds.size;

            CGFloat w=scrollViewSize.width/newZoomscal;
            CGFloat h=scrollViewSize.height /newZoomscal;
            CGFloat x= Pointview.x-(w/2.0);
            CGFloat y = Pointview.y-(h/2.0);

            CGRect rectTozoom=CGRectMake(x, y, w, h);
            [self zoomToRect:rectTozoom animated:YES]; 

            [self setZoomScale:3.0 animated:YES]; 
            zoomCheck=NO;
        }
        else{ 
            [self setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES]; 
            zoomCheck=YES;
        }
    }
```

use this code so it will zoom where you click.......
zoomChech is bool variable for checking zoom

Comment: This is excellent. If you use the if-else conditional from the @possen answer then it's even better!

Answer (score 3):

It is the latest code with swift 5 for Pinch zoom and double tap zoom.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    scrollView.delegate = self

    let doubleTapGest = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer:)))
    doubleTapGest.numberOfTapsRequired = 2
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(doubleTapGest)
}

func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
    return imageView
}

@objc func handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if scrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
        scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
    }
    else {
        scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
    }
}

func zoomRectForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
    var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
    zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height / scale
    zoomRect.size.width  = imageView.frame.size.width  / scale
    let newCenter = imageView.convert(center, from: scrollView)
    zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
    zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
    return zoomRect
}


}
```

I attached storyboard picture too.

[image]

Comment: Hi, how would you change to make it zoom in /out the same way: I mean incremental to the taped location, ie, if you make the else as follows: `scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollView.zoomScale*2, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Previous answer could be simpler with [BlocksKit](https://github.com/zwaldowski/BlocksKit), like below.

```
#import "BlocksKit.h"
...
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithHandler:^(UIGestureRecognizer *sender, UIGestureRecognizerState state, CGPoint location) {
    if(scrollView.zoomScale != 1.0){
        [scrollView setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
    }else{
        [scrollView setZoomScale:2.0 animated:YES];
    }
}];
[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
[scrollView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

Comment: Seems like you should be able to do all of that without any third party code, no?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to implement `viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? in UIScrollViewDelegate` in order to get @n8tr's answer working.

[image]

So the complete code will look something like this

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self
    }

    @IBAction func handleDoubleTapScrollView(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
        if scrollView.zoomScale == 1 {
            scrollView.zoom(to: zoomRectForScale(scale: scrollView.maximumZoomScale, center: recognizer.location(in: recognizer.view)), animated: true)
        } else {
            scrollView.setZoomScale(1, animated: true)
        }
    }

    func zoomRectForScale(scale: CGFloat, center: CGPoint) -> CGRect {
        var zoomRect = CGRect.zero
        zoomRect.size.height = imageView.frame.size.height / scale
        zoomRect.size.width  = imageView.frame.size.width  / scale
        let newCenter = imageView.convert(center, from: scrollView)
        zoomRect.origin.x = newCenter.x - (zoomRect.size.width / 2.0)
        zoomRect.origin.y = newCenter.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0)
        return zoomRect
    }


    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {
        return imageView
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about adding a UITapGestureRecognizer to the ImageScrollView?

As long as you are looking at sample code, you can check out how UIGestureRecognizers are used in the [ScrollViewSuite sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply I will try using UITapGestureRecognizer; but the UITapGestureRecognizer is supported for iOS 3.2 and above. How to achieve the above functionality in iPhone 3.0 ?

Answer (score 0):

Subclass the UIScrollView an in m file add

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark doubleTouch

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    NSUInteger tapCount = [touch tapCount];
    switch (tapCount) {
        case 2:
        {
            if(self.zoomScale <1.0){
                [self setZoomScale:1.0 animated:YES];
            }else{
                [self setZoomScale:0.1 animated:YES];
            }

            break;
        }
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work using `convertRect:fromView:` and `zoomToRect:animated:`:

```
-(void)tap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    CGFloat zoomeScaleMultiplier = 0.5;
    UIScrollView *scrollView = (UIScrollView *) tapGestureRecognizer.view;
    UIView *zoomableView = [scrollView.delegate viewForZoomingInScrollView:scrollView];

    CGRect rect = scrollView.bounds;
    rect.origin = CGPointZero;

    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(zoomeScaleMultiplier, zoomeScaleMultiplier);
    rect = CGRectApplyAffineTransform(rect, transform);

    rect.origin = [tapGestureRecognizer locationInView:scrollView];

    rect = CGRectOffset(rect, CGRectGetWidth(rect)/-2., CGRectGetHeight(rect)/-2.);

    rect = [zoomableView convertRect:rect fromView:scrollView];

    [scrollView zoomToRect:rect animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Zooms in on tap location

```
CGFloat scale = 3.0;
CGFloat scale = ScaleToAspectFitRectAroundRect(frame, self.bounds) * 2.0;

CGRect zoomRect;
CGPoint point = [gestureRecognizer locationOfTouch:0 inView:[gestureRecognizer view]];

zoomRect.size.height = frame.size.height * scale;
zoomRect.size.width  = frame.size.width  * scale;

zoomRect.origin.x = CGRectGetMidX(frame) - (CGRectGetWidth(zoomRect)/2) + (scale * (CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - point.x)) - (CGRectGetWidth(frame)/2 - point.x);
zoomRect.origin.y = CGRectGetMidY(frame) - (CGRectGetHeight(zoomRect)/2) + (scale * (CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2 - point.y)) - (CGRectGetHeight(frame)/2 - point.y);
```

Answer (score -1):

here my code work for me it's simple :

```
// Listen for Double Tap Zoom
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];

[doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];

[self addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
```

you need

```
BOOL checkZoomImage;
```

Here tab method

```
- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {

    if (self.zoomScale > self.minimumZoomScale && self.zoomScale == self.maximumZoomScale){
        checkZoomImage = YES;
    }
    if (self.zoomScale < self.maximumZoomScale && self.zoomScale == self.minimumZoomScale) {
        checkZoomImage = NO;
    }


    if (checkZoomImage) {
        [self setZoomScale:self.zoomScale *0.5 animated:YES];
    }else{
        [self setZoomScale:self.zoomScale *1.5 animated:YES];
    }

}
```

Comment: you mean double tap? or single tap?

Comment: Double tap. Your code just zooms in when double tapped, without taking care to calculate the area where it's tapped and then calling zoomToRect.