# UIImageView does not zoom

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I would like to zoom an image on a popup view.

I've created the UIView subclass, based on [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/ScrollViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008904) sample code:

ZoomView.h:

```
@interface ZoomView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate> {
    UIScrollView *imageScrollView;
    UIImageView *imageView;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *imageScrollView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageView;

@end
```

ZoomView.m:

```
#import "ZoomView.h"

#define ZOOM_VIEW_TAG 100
#define ZOOM_STEP 1.5

@interface ZoomView (UtilityMethods)
- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center;
@end

@implementation ZoomView
@synthesize imageScrollView;
@synthesize imageView;


- (void)awakeFromNib{

}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)loadView
{
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];

    // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];

    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    return [imageScrollView viewWithTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale+0.01 animated:NO];
    [scrollView setZoomScale:scale animated:NO];
}

#pragma mark TapDetectingImageViewDelegate methods

- (void)handleSingleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // single tap does nothing for now
}

- (void)handleDoubleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // double tap zooms in
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] * ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

- (void)handleTwoFingerTap:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    // two-finger tap zooms out
    float newScale = [imageScrollView zoomScale] / ZOOM_STEP;
    CGRect zoomRect = [self zoomRectForScale:newScale withCenter:[gestureRecognizer locationInView:gestureRecognizer.view]];
    [imageScrollView zoomToRect:zoomRect animated:YES];
}

#pragma mark Utility methods

- (CGRect)zoomRectForScale:(float)scale withCenter:(CGPoint)center {
    CGRect zoomRect;

    zoomRect.size.height = [imageScrollView frame].size.height / scale;
    zoomRect.size.width  = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / scale;

    zoomRect.origin.x    = center.x - (zoomRect.size.width  / 2.0);
    zoomRect.origin.y    = center.y - (zoomRect.size.height / 2.0);

    return zoomRect;
}

@end
```

In my nib file, I've set the view's class to ZoomView, made the connections between the view, the `imageScrollView`, `imageView` and `delegate`, but after running the code, the image does not zoom. What did I omit to do?

Comment: did you set min/max zoom in IB?

Comment: Yes, I did set min and max zoom too.

Comment: what about adding the gesture recognizers to the scroll view, not the enclosed image view?

Comment: it recognizes... I've put some NSLogs inside the methods, and it displays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have taken small image. You have to take bigger image. I think it will be worked.Try like that.

Answer (score 0):

Try delegating from imageScrollView to self. -> imageScrollView.delegate = self;