# Free Scrolling in Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, xcode, uiscrollview

I want to create a page with a big image as background and buttons that users can interact with.

So imagine I put a big image such as a piece of map into the screen, but I only show a corner of the map in the display. So if a user wants to see other parts of the map, they have to "scroll" and navigate to wherever they want.

Meanwhile I also want to put a button they can tap on, and that button should lead to a php webpage (in-app, not opening in safari or else) or information page about sites and buildings in this location.

I am a rookie and I haven't have any code written down yet. I am thinking about using UIScrollView and UIButton, but am I on the right direction? Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: in which language you want to do this ? because you are added not related tag in question .

Comment: @ Andrew :- You are going in the right direction. Use UIScrollView and UIButton

Comment: @KKRocks I am using swift3.0

Comment: @Coder I tried UIScrollView, but not sure how to work it out. Many tutorials on the internet seem to be vertical scroll or horizontal scroll, but I would like the users to free scroll just like in Google Map

Answer (score 0):

First you need a way to pinch zoom the image. In this mode, you can drag the image in any direction that you want. A common method can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014241/uiimageview-pinch-zoom-swift). A scroll view can only scroll horizontally or vertically but with that image zooming, each image can be zoomed in and then dragged to any direction you want. You can have a scroll view with only one image.

After you have the image zooming ready, all you need to do is to create a subview on your screen to cover part of the image view or scroll view, whatever you used.