# Swift pinch zoom image quality

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiimage, pinchzoom

I'm creating an image from a text field and I'm wanting to scale up the newly created image when a user pinches/zooms. The problem I'm getting is that the quality of the image becomes pixelated and I can't seem to think of a fix.

```
func imageFromTextfield(text: UITextField) -> UIView {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(text.intrinsicContentSize, false, UIScreen.main.scale)
    text.drawHierarchy(in: text.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    if let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() {

        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        // Draggable view returns the pinch gesture
        let textImage: DraggableView = {
            let view = DraggableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height))
            view.stickerImage.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: image.size.width, height: image.size.height)
            view.stickerImage.image = image
            view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
            view.clipsToBounds = false
            view.layer.masksToBounds = false
            view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.stickerImage.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
            return view
        }()
        return textImage
    }
    return UIView()

}
```

I've tried increasing the font size and scaling down the frame but this doesn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: I think refer this link:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014241/uiimageview-pinch-zoom-swift

Comment: you should use  scrollView for pich zoom .

Comment: So I need to convert the textfield to an image and then house this in a resulting scrollview?? Seems like the wrong approach.

Comment: @user7684436 you need the textfield as image? this is mandatory?

Comment: Yes, a user creates the image from a textfield input.