# Zoom into UIView without pixelating

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, drawing, uibezierpath

I have a drawing app that uses UIBezierpaths (vectors) and I'm trying to create a function that allows me to zoom around the canvas/UIView like other drawing apps do. I do not want to enlarge individual bezierpaths, I already know how to do that. I want a pinch to zoom functionality *like safari* that zooms the canvas/view.

If I use the following code:

```
self.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2, y: 2)
```

This:
[image]

Turns into this, which you'll notice is quite blurry/not smooth like vectors are supposed to be:
[image]

But I want it to look something like this, which is what would happen on another drawing app[image]

I understand this question may have a complicated answer, but I'm struggling to find that answer by myself.

Comment: If you want to implement vector zooming, you should recalculate the points yourself. `CGAffineTransform` is not vector-based.

Comment: CGaffinetransform does enlarge uibezierpaths correctly, but I want to transform the view

Answer (score 0):

I have made a drawing app that was able to zoom in. I didn't remember How I managed to handle this.
But I think you should definitely use UIScrollView to manage the zooming / dragging part.
[UIImageView pinch zoom swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014241/uiimageview-pinch-zoom-swift)

You will be able to pinch to zoom, drag etc for almost free. 
And It will not be pixelated I think

Comment: Thanks for this. I was playing with this earlier with no success assuming this wasn't the solution, but will keep trying now you've informed me it probably is the solution

Answer (score 0):

Add a `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to your drawing view. Then handle the delegate events from them to update your scale and offset. You then finally use resulting scale and offset to redraw (by calling `setNeedsDisplay()` typically).

I can tell you from experience that these calculations are a bit tricky but doable.