# Keep pannable UIView inside bounds

Tags: ios, geometry

I am developing an iOS application which contains a scalable and pannable `UIView`.  Since the user is allowed to pan and scale the view, I did like to keep the `UIView` within the boundaries of the screen.

I searched a lot on the internet, but there does not seem to be examples that really fits my need.

Below is the panning code I wrote:

```
private void HandlePan(UIPanGestureRecognizer recognizer)
{
    if (recognizer.State != UIGestureRecognizerState.Began &&
        recognizer.State != UIGestureRecognizerState.Changed)
        return;

    var translation = recognizer.TranslationInView(this);

    _posX += translation.X;
    _posY += translation.Y;

    var maxX = (Bounds.Size.Width / 2) * _currentScale;
    var maxY = (Bounds.Size.Height / 2) * _currentScale;

    // TODO: The min values are wrong
    var minX = (Bounds.Size.Width / 2) / _currentScale;
    var minY = (Bounds.Size.Height / 2) / _currentScale;

    if (_posX > maxX)
        _posX = maxX;
    else if (_posX < minX)
        _posX = minX;
    if (_posY > maxY)
        _posY = maxY;
    else if (_posY < minY)
        _posY = minY;

    var translatedCenter = new CGPoint(_posX, _posY);
    Center = translatedCenter;

    recognizer.SetTranslation(CGPoint.Empty, this);
}
```

I managed to get the boundaries working with only two sides of the screen. `maxX` and `maxY` are correct. I just can't figure out the way on how to calculate the correct `minX` and `minY` values.

Below I added a screen recording to show what is going wrong:

[image: Screen recording]

You can see that the coordinates are blocking (even more when the scale is incrementing > 1) when I try to drag to the right/bottom side of the image (which are the `minX` and `minY` values).

What is wrong in this calculation or what should the correct calculation be? Note that `maxX` and `maxY` are perfectly working.

```
var minX = (Bounds.Size.Width / 2) / _currentScale;
var minY = (Bounds.Size.Height / 2) / _currentScale;
```

Comment: If you just want to zoom in/zoom-out an UIImageView, then you should use ScrollView's inbuilt method.

Comment: @SharadChauhan, cool I didn't know that. Thanks.

Comment: You can refer this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/41179677/6059313

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another approach for **calculating boundaries** could also be:

```
int centerPoint = (int)(Bounds.Size.Width / 2);

var minX = centerPoint - ((_currentScale - 1) * centerPoint);
if (_posX < minX)
    _posX = minX;
```

Answer (score 0):

After lots of trial and error I managed to fix it by moving the image manually to the borders of the frame and writing down all the values.

The values looked like this:

```
Bounds = 375
maxX = 187.5, minX = 187.5, scale = 1
maxX = 549.039223765595, minX = -173.989914508274, scale = 2.92820919341651
maxX = 915.278849493097, minX = -539.668274239639, scale = 4.88052876267261
maxX = 1575.12891219963, minX = -1198.9316584188, scale = 8.40338022601214
```

Which means that the following formula is able to get the `min` values.

```
var minX = -(maxX - Bounds.Size.Width);
var minY = -(maxY - Bounds.Size.Height);
```

Now it's working fine.