# Swift pinch to zoom

Tags: swift, imageview, scrollview, pinch

I'm trying to add an image and scrollview programmatically to swift, and then allow them to be pinched to zoom.

I've followed the instructions from [UIImageView pinch zoom swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30014241/uiimageview-pinch-zoom-swift) but am still not able to pinch to zoom, I'm not sure what I'm missing

```
class mapViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate, IALocationManagerDelegate {

    var imageViewBackground: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        super.viewDidLoad()

        let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width
        let height = UIScreen.main.bounds.size.height

        let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width-70, height:height-60))
        var image: UIImage?
        let urlString = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/coxur-59760.appspot.com/o/Maps%2FCapture.png?alt=media&token=741b1425-cb01-453b-8c40-47f6e5fd528d"

        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)! as URL
        if let imageData: NSData = NSData(contentsOf: url) {
            image = UIImage(data: imageData as Data)
        }
        imageViewBackground.image = image

        // you can change the content mode:
        imageViewBackground.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill

        var scrollView: UIScrollView!
        scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 120, width: width, height: height))
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: width, height: 2000)
        scrollView.delegate = self
        scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0
        scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 6.0

        scrollView.addSubview(imageViewBackground)
        self.view.addSubview(scrollView)
        //self.view.sendSubviewToBack(imageViewBackground)
    }
    func viewForZooming(in scrollView: UIScrollView) -> UIView? {

        return imageViewBackground
    }


}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: This is not relevant to the actual question you are asking, but never never never call `NSData(contentsOf: url)` with a remote URL. Download the image data asynchronously through proper means.

Comment: Why is that? I'm using a remote url because I want to be able to update it after publishing the app

Comment: I didn't say don't use a remote URL. I said don't fetch it by saying `NSData(contentsOf:)`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is this line:

```
let imageViewBackground = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:width-70, height:height-60))
```

Delete `let`. Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry do not have the reputation to comment but could it possibly be that you are initializing the scrollView inside of the viewDidLoad instead of making it a class variable?